# Output of my VHDL code is becoming reset dependent

Tags: vhdl

it's me again! 
First I'd like to say that I learnt VHDL a few days ago and I'm quite a newbie at this, so I tend to make silly mistakes. Any suggestions would be great. 
I've written a VHDL code for a module which can be used as a memory controller.

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity memory_controller is
port(clk: in std_logic;
     reset: in std_logic;
     bus_id: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     read_write, burst: in std_logic;
     ready: in std_logic;
     oe, we: out std_logic;
     addr_1, addr_2: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
     );
end memory_controller;
architecture behavioral of memory_controller is
    type statetype is (idle, decision, wr, rd1, rd2, rd3, rd4);
    signal present_state, next_state : statetype;
    signal addr_int : integer range 0 to (2**addr_1'length)-1;
    begin
    Synch_reset: process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if (reset ='0') then
                present_state <= next_state;  
            else
                present_state <= idle;   
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;  
    decision_logic: process(present_state, read_write, ready, burst)
    begin
        case present_state is
            when idle => 
                oe <= '0'; we <= '0'; addr_int <= 0;
                addr_1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_1'length));
                addr_2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_2'length));
                if(bus_id = "11110011") then
                    next_state <= decision;
                else
                    next_state <= idle;
                end if;
            when decision =>
                if (read_write = '1') then 
                    next_state <= rd1;
                else 
                    next_state <= wr;
                end if;
            when wr =>
                we <= '1';
                if (ready = '1') then 
                    next_state <= idle;
                else
                    next_state <= wr;
                end if;
            when rd1 =>
                oe <= '1';
                if(ready = '0') then
                    next_state <= rd1;
                else
                    if(burst = '0') then
                        next_state <= idle;
                    else 
                        next_state <= rd2;
                        addr_int <= addr_int + 1;
                addr_1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_1'length));
                addr_2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_2'length));
                    end if;
                end if;
            when rd2 =>
                oe <= '1';
                if(ready = '1') then
                    next_state <= rd3;
                    addr_int <= addr_int + 1;
                addr_1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_1'length));
                addr_2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_2'length));
                else
                    next_state <= rd2;
                end if;
            when rd3 =>
                oe <= '1';
                if(ready = '1') then 
                    next_state <= rd4;
                    addr_int <= addr_int + 1;
                addr_1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_1'length));
                addr_2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_2'length));
                else
                    next_state <= rd3;
                end if;
            when rd4 =>
                oe <= '1';
                if(ready = '1') then 
                    next_state <= idle;
                else 
                    next_state <= rd4;
                end if;
         end case;
     end process;
end behavioral;
```

Here's my test bench:

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity memory_controller_tb is
end memory_controller_tb;
architecture test of memory_controller_tb is
component memory_controller
port(clk: in std_logic;
     reset: in std_logic;
     bus_id: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     read_write, burst: in std_logic;
     ready: in std_logic;
     oe, we: out std_logic;
     addr_1, addr_2: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
     );
end component;
signal clk: std_logic;
signal reset: std_logic;
signal read_write, burst, oe, we: std_logic;
signal addr_1, addr_2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ready: std_logic;
signal bus_id: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal StopClock : boolean := FALSE;
begin
UUT :memory_controller
port map( clk => clk,
          reset => reset,
          bus_id => bus_id,
          read_write => read_write,
          burst => burst,
          ready => ready,
          oe => oe,
          we => we,
          addr_1 => addr_1,
          addr_2 => addr_2);
clk_process: process
begin
while not StopClock loop
clk <= '0';
wait for 5 ns;
clk <= '1';
wait for 5 ns;
end loop;
end process clk_process;
stim: process is
begin
reset <= '1', '0' after 50 ns;
bus_id <= "11110011";
wait for 5 ns;
read_write <= '0';
wait for 5 ns;
ready <= '1';
bus_id <= "11110011";
wait for 5 ns;
read_write <= '1';
assert (ready <='1' and burst <= '1')
report "Illegal state"
severity error;
assert (ready <= '1' and burst <='0')
report "Illegal state"
severity error;
wait for 5 ns;
ready <= '0';
wait for 5 ns;
burst <= '0';
wait for 5 ns;
ready <= '1';
wait for 5 ns;
burst <= '1';
wait for 5 ns;
ready <= '0';
wait for 5 ns;
ready <= '1';
wait for 5 ns;
ready <= '1';
end process;
end test;

configuration CFG_memory_controller of memory_controller_tb is
    for test
        for UUT : memory_controller
        end for;
    end for;
end;
```

When burst is asserted it should go throught read1 read2 read3 and read4 on assertion of ready(as in when burst = 1 it should go on to read 2, read 3, read 4 if ready is 1) and must not go into the idle state if reset becomes 0 anytime in between. But it does for me. How do I change the program so that it is not dependent on the reset?

Also, the address doesn't get reset to 0 when it is reset to go back into idle state. When I try to change the code it says that I was trying to assert addresses from multiple places.

Also I think my test bench writing skills suck, are there any sort of rules or guidelines to follow or do you have to just develop an instinct for it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. get rid of "wait for 5 ns;", make that "wait until rising_edge(clk);". This way you will make sure that you don't get any delta cycle issues. 2. Your controller code is a bit dodgy: I am sure you want addr_int (at least) to be a register, otherwise your counters do funny things. Then come back ;-)

Comment: I think you're writing software, not hardware anymore. Please read your book carefully: some signal is assign such as `a <= a+1` or `a <= 1` then `b= a+2` in combination logic. So, what do you think it become. Please through away your software thinking. If not, no one can define you error. P/S: HDL is hardware **description** language. You're not programming, you're describing. The HDL code must lead to  a architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You have a combinational loop: you read and write the signal `addr_int` in your combinational process, which causes all sorts of problems. Either create a signal `next_addr_int` and assign that in the clocked process, or put everything in a single clocked process.

Other problems with the code:

- `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned` are deprecated. Use `ieee.numeric_std` instead.
- Conversions like this make your code hard to understand: `addr_1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(addr_int, addr_1'length));` Use `unsigned` instead of `std_logic_vector` instead.
- In your reset clause, people will assume reset is active low since you check for `reset = '0'`. Instead, check for `reset = '1'` and reverse the `if` and `else` parts. I guess the tools won't mind your coding style, but it confuses humans.